# How to find documents by a field from a ref?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have the following two schemas:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schemaA = new Schema({
    tag: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'schemaB',
        },
    ],
});

module.exports = SchemaA = mongoose.model('schemaA', schemaA);
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schemaB = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
    }
});

module.exports = SchemaB = mongoose.model('schemaB', schemaB);
```

How can I find all documents in `SchemaA` that have their `tag` field match the name of `SchemaB`?

I know that if I had the `_id` of `SchemaB`, I'd be able to do this as,

```
const schemaBId = 'some-_id-string'
const docs = await SchemaA.find({ tag: schemaBId })
```

But how can I do this, if I only have the `name` value?

Comment: you need to use aggregation pipeline query and [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage

Comment: you can do like this schemaA.find().populate({path: 'tag', match:{name: 'test'}})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first use lookup to get data of ModelB and then put these data as `t` after that make query with match to find where name of ModelB is test

```
ModelA.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'collectionB',
            localField: 'tag',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 't',
        },
    },
    {
        $match: { 't.name': 'test' },
    },
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using mongoose `populate()` function it might help you achieve exactly what you want. Here is the [populate docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) for quick reference.